# Rspec ActionController::UrlGenerationError Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using Rails 4.2 rspec 3.5

after basic scaffold generation, i was trying to run rspec, but constantly getting this errors.

controller test

```
it "updates the requested" do
    some_object = SomeObject.create! valid_attributes
    put :update, params: {id: some_object.to_param, some_object: new_attributes}, session: valid_session
    some_object.reload
    skip("Add assertions for updated state")
end
```

gives this output

```
Failure/Error: put :update, params: {id: some_object.to_param, some_object: valid_attributes}, session: valid_session

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"update"
```

And views test

```
  require 'rails_helper'

  RSpec.describe "some_objects/edit", type: :view do
    before(:each) do
      @some_object = assign(:some_object, SomeObject.create!(
        :first_name => "MyString",
        :last_name => "MyString"
      ))
    end

    it "renders the edit some_object form" do
      render

      assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", some_object_path(@some_object), "post" do

        assert_select "input#some_object_first_name[name=?]", "some_object[first_name]"

        assert_select "input#some_object_last_name[name=?]", "some_object[last_name]"
      end
    end
  end
```

gives this output:

```
Failure/Error: <%= form_for(@some_object) do |f| %>

  ActionView::Template::Error:
    undefined method `polymorphic_path' for #<#<Class:0x005606c04fff98>:0x005606c04ffb60>
```

This is generated code. I have changed only valid_attributes hash, and this seem to be some bug in rails/rspec. Do you have any solution

Comment: How does your `config/routes.rb` look like? What is the real class name of the thing that you called `some_object` in your example? How does that class look like?

Comment: class SomeObject < ActiveRecord::Base
   end

That's pure model from scaffold.

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :some_objects
end

Comment: Does your database table have a column with the name `type`?

Comment: rails generate scaffold some_object first_name:string last_name:string

and db:migrate in test env

so that's makes me worry the most. Because this is generated code. And application works fine. This is only controller and view test issue.

Comment: OK i found a solution. For broken templates was removing gem rails-controller-testing from gemfile (i didn't need it). And for controller test it's just params: {id: some_object.to_param, some_object: new_attributes} => {id: some_object.to_param, some_object: new_attributes} (removing params: leaving hash as second parameter, probably discrepancy between rspec and rails) thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in passing params for :update. Simply remove **params:** and it will work:

```
it "updates the requested" do
    some_object = SomeObject.create! valid_attributes
    put :update, {id: some_object.to_param, some_object: new_attributes}, session: valid_session
    some_object.reload
    skip("Add assertions for updated state")
end
```